# Trigger a function after modify select value in children component - VueJs

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-props

I'm using VueJs and i have this children component in my father component, i need to trigger a function in the parent component, when the change in the select of the child component is detected.

**Children component:**

```
watch: {
    selectCoin() {
      this.$emit("currencyType", this.selectCoin["title"]);
    }
}
```

Children component in my **Father Component:**

```
<app-select-coin
  @coin="body.value = $event"
  @currencyType="body.currencyType = $event"
  :data="body"
/>
```

I need to call this method when the child component responds to $emit for the parent component:

```
methods :{
   myFunction() {

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it by adding the function in the "v-on" in @currencyType, and passing as parameter the values ​​i received from the children in "$emit".:

```
<app-select-coin
  @coin="body.value = $event"
  @currencyType="myFunction(body.currencyType = $event)"
  :data="body"
/>
```

```
methods :{
   myFunction(ct) {

   }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).